# Pausing Unity game without "Time.timeScale = 0"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to find a way to pause my game in Unity without using "Time.timeScale = 0;". The reason I want to change this is that I want to make the character play an animation while the game is paused. Is there a way to change this script so that the gravity and forward speed only "sets in" after the player have clicked space? Or is there a better way to solve the problem?

This is the script:

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 gravity;
    public Vector3 FlyVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f; 

    bool didFly = false;
    bool dead = false;
    float deathCooldown;
    Animator animator;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }

    // Do Graphic & Input updates here
    void Update(){
        if (dead) {
            deathCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (deathCooldown <= 0) {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) ) {
                Application.LoadLevel( Application.loadedLevel );
                    }
                }
            }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) ) {
            didFly = true;
            animator.SetTrigger ("DoFly");
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        animator.SetTrigger ("Death");
        dead = true;
    }

    // Do physics engine updates here
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (dead)
            return;

        velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.x = forwardSpeed;

        if(didFly == true) {
            didFly = false;
            velocity += FlyVelocity;
        }

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);

        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        deathCooldown = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find more help for unity over on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is nothing built into unity for this. But i recommend having a look at state machines since they help when you have different states like this (paused/playing) and when thing need to be done when entering/exiting states.

Comment: I know this thread is a bit old, but you can try my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718168/pausing-in-unity/31718377#31718377

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mechanim you could update animation state from script using [Animator.Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Update.html) even while actual time scale is zero.

Not sure if the trick is possible with legacy animation.