# How to play animations while the game is paused (timescale = 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to pause a game in Unity using by setting timeScale to 0 when the pause panel comes up, and setting it back to 1 when the panel is disabled. The problem I am having is that when I Pause, the buttons on the panel are not showing their animation as the time scale is 0. Is there anyway around this? Or should I find another way to do the pause without using the timescale?

Answer (score 15):

In your Animator component look for **Update Mode** option and select **Unscaled Time**. Like this :

[image: Use Unscaled Time as Update Mode]

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is to maintain state of your game using `Enum`. e.g., define an enum as:

```
enum GameState
{
    Started,
    Loading,
    Playing,
    Paused,
    Completed
}
```

Declare a variable of type `GameState` in your session or any place where access is easy to you, then compare:

```
if(currentGameState == GameState.Playing)
{
      // Play logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

To fix your animations issue . Simply make the animation to play in unscaled time. That way the animation plays even if Time.timeScale is 0. You can do this by setting the update mode of the animator to Unscaled time.